# How to solve ReferenceError: myfunction123 is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, uncaught-reference-error

i am trying to fetch the items in the array using map and call back funtion.

here is the html code

```
`enter code here`
  <p id="myid6"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="myfunction123()">myfunction123</button><br></br>
```

This is my javascript code

```
let abj = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let abbn = abj.map(myfuntion123)


function myfuntion123(item) {
  console.log(item * 4)
}
```

ERROR

> Blockquote ReferenceError: myfunction123 is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

HOW TO FIX THIS ERROR?????

Comment: Is this the only function that does not work or does nothing from the javascript file work? Are you referencing the js script inside your html?

Comment: Typo: `myfuntion123` is missing the `c`

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be due to your javascript function name being called "myfuntion123" while in your html you are calling "myfun**c**tion123"

The names do not match. It's missing a "c".

Comment: Please do not post answers to typo questions, instead flag the question as typo and help op in a comment